# How to include a content page in jsp in aem?

Tags: aem, sling

How can I include one of my AEM page from content in my component's JSP?

I have a page created at /content/www-mysite-com/en/page1 which has parsys and components dragged and dropped in it and now I want to include this content in a a components  so that my component's author-ability is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use sling include tag from sling tag librabry

```
<div id="someDiv">
    <c:set var="mypage" value="/content/www-mysite-com/en/page1" />
    <sling:include path="${mypage}.content.html" />
</div>
```